# Close voting menu broken on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

On my Android 4.0.3 browser, the vote to close menu will no longer appear if a vote has already been given:
[image]

The site will focus on the close button and seems to try to load something, but no menu opens. 
If I haven't given my vote yet, it works just fine:
[image]

I noticed this on superuser.com

Additionally, I think it would be great if the number of votes other people have placed would be easier distinguishable from the rest of the text in that menu. Sadly, I don't have a screenshot for that.

Comment: Reproducible on Windows Phone 7.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data you see when closing (again) after already voting wasn't really meant to be on the mobile site, it's not terribly interesting on the main sites IMO.

The next deploy will actually disable that link in this case, so I guess that "fixes" the problem.

Comment: The behavior was mostly just confusing, so this will be very appreciated. How about those vote number indicator? Should I open a new question when I have an image of the issue?