# Unable to "flag" or "close" from mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, android

There have reports of issues with mobile site's ability to "flag" or "close" questions:

- [Can't vote to close from the mobile site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102389/cant-vote-to-close-from-the-mobile-site)
- [Close voting menu broken on mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124690/close-voting-menu-broken-on-mobile-site)

This seemed to have been fixed, however, when the new categories of close/flag votes were introduced the issue has reoccurred again.

As of now I am unable to "close" or "flag" from the mobile interface to the site.